# Creating a popover from a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, popover

I wish to create a small popover about `50x50px` from a `UIButton`. I have seen methods using adaptive segue's but I have my size classes turn of thus meaning I can not use this features!

How else can I create this popover? Can I create it with code inside my button `IBACtion`? Or is there still a way I can do this with storyboards?

Answer (score 15):

You can do one of the following two options :

- Create an action for the `UIButton` in your `UIViewController` and inside present the `ViewController` you want like a Popover and your `UIViewController` has to implement the protocol `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, take a look in the following code :

  ```
  @IBAction func showPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

      var popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdentifier") as! UIViewController

      popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
      var popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController

      if let popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController {

         let viewForSource = sender as! UIView
         popover.sourceView = viewForSource

         // the position of the popover where it's showed
         popover.sourceRect = viewForSource.bounds

         // the size you want to display
         popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,500)
         popover.delegate = self
      }            

      self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
     return .None
  }
  ```

  According to the book of @matt ***Programming iOS 8***:

  > A popover presentation controller, in iOS 8, is a presentation controller (`UIPresentationController`), and presentation controllers are adaptive. This means that, by default, in a horizontally compact environment (i.e. on an iPhone), the `.Popover` modal presentation style will be treated as `.FullScreen`. What appears as a popover on the iPad will appear as a fullscreen presented view on the iPhone, completely replacing the interface.

  To avoid this behavior in the iPhone you need to implement the delegate method  [`adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate/adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:) inside your `UIViewController` to display the Popover correctly.
- The other way in my opinion is more easy to do, and is using Interface Builder, just arrange from the `UIButton` to create a segue to the `ViewController` you want and in the segue select the `Popover` segue.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for this! The first example works but it dosnt seem to chaange the size. The popover just comes up full screen.

I think the second way you explained would be a better way.. But once again I get a error couldn't comply connection IBCocoaTouchoutlet anchor View.

Could you give me some code that would go along with the second way you explained?

Comment: @user4671001 I don't understand, in the seconde way you not need to set the anchoView for nothing

Comment: popover shows as fullscreen modal on iphones, you can disable this by adding this function:`func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(PC: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // This *forces* a popover to be displayed on the iPhone
    return .None
}`

Comment: Same in Swift2. Xcode shows an error about the anchor. Any solutions?

Comment: @lukesIvi You not have to set the anchor in the above code and the code works in iOS 9 and Swift2.

Comment: Can you send a repository over github? I'm trying to go one from viewControllerKOne to another while passing a URL  from viewControllerOne to the url VC and then going back to the VCOne. I don't want to send data back and forth. Instead, I just want to send to the URL VC and then go right back without having to reload data to the VCOne. Any ideas?

Comment: Just give me a moment I'll upload a repository and I update some topics in my answer.

Comment: @lukesIvi See updated answer and if you need the repo yet let me know and I'll upload it to Github

Comment: Thanks, i got it working in a similar fashion but with less code. I could post the answer/the gist if anyone is interested. PS, this did help though.

Comment: @VictorSigler can you provide this code in objective-c? check my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308025/how-to-create-popover-clicked-on-button

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4** Here is fully working code. So here you will see popup window with size of 250x250:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

// in case if you don't want to make it via IBAction
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        @objc
        private func tapped() {

            guard let popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") else { return }

            popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

            let popOverVC = popVC.popoverPresentationController
            popOverVC?.delegate = self
            popOverVC?.sourceView = self.button
            popOverVC?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.button.bounds.midX, y: self.button.bounds.minY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)

            self.present(popVC, animated: true)
        }
    }


// This is we need to make it looks as a popup window on iPhone
    extension ViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

        func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
            return .none
        }
    }
```

Take into attention that you have to provide popVC identifier to one viewController you want to present as a popup.

Hope that helps!

Comment: can you provide this code in objective-c? Please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308025/how-to-create-popover-clicked-on-button

Answer (score 2):

Here you can present a popover on button click.

```
func addCategory( _ sender : UIButton) {

        var popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as UIViewController
        var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
        popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50,50)
        popover.delegate = self
        popover.sourceView = sender
        popover.sourceRect = sender.bounds

        self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 Version**

*Doing most work from the storyboard*

I added a `ViewController`, went to it's attribute inspector and ticked the "Use Preferred Explicit size". After that I changed the Width and Height values to 50 each.

Once this was done I ctrl clicked and dragged from the Button to the `ViewController` I added choosing "Present as Popover" and naming the segue Identifier as "pop"

Went to the `ViewController`  where I had my Button and added the following code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var popoverButton: UIButton! // the button

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pop" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destination
            popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            popoverViewController.presentationController?.delegate = self
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = popoverButton
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: popoverButton.frame.size.width, height: popoverButton.frame.size.height)
        }
    }
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```