# How to create popover clicked on button?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uipopovercontroller, xcode8.2

I want to create popover clicked on button in objective c. [My refresh is this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)  . I need this type of design, just check below image.How to implement this one. I am unable to find exact solution.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, what part is not working?

Comment: after clicking on button, not open/appear view.

Comment: Please share your code - otherwise it's impossible to guess what the problem is.